# sql - determine first set of records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I want to make a paging:

```
< page >
```

where `<` indicates previous 10 posts and `>` means next 10 records.

I understand we can use:

For First 10 records:

```
SELECT some_column FROM Table WHERE some_column ORDER BY some_column LIMIT 10
```

For next 10 records:

```
SELECT some_column FROM Table WHERE some_column ORDER BY some_column LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

For last 10 records:

```
SELECT some_column FROM Table WHERE some_column ORDER BY some_column DESC LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that: say I'm viewing 11 - 20 records, and I click to preview the 1 - 10 records.

I want `<` disappear while I'm viewing `1 - 10 records` so that user will not abuse the `<` to non stop sending query to database.

P.S. I am using a hosted mysql server.

Comment: check in mysql min and max key , then compare with existing. if you're result set containing that key dont display > or <

Comment: The pseudo SQL looks fine but the question is about a page.  What do you have so far in PHP?

Comment: Should be pretty simple: `if (not first page) show <` or something like that. Impossible to really be much help without seeing your code, though.

Comment: So you probably use a variable to take track of how much offset and limit to use, like `$page`, if `$page` is `0` don't show the `<`.

Comment: @MikeSteder, I have a php fucntion which currently fetching 10 records and displaying in html table format...if that is what you asking

Comment: @ddw147 Therefore, I will have a query to use min to determine the first record, and another query to fetch records? Is there by any chance that it can be a one-line query?

Comment: just check if you're currently on the first page, hide it if it is, same goes with `>`, check if you're on the last page, if it is, hide it

Comment: @Ghost currently I don't have a indication if its first/last page. The page is just basically fetching 10 records and display in table form when user clicked the link...to determine first page, how should i do it? Thanks :D

Comment: @Andrew select min(ID)  ,  max (ID) from yourtable :- ID is key to yourtable

Comment: @ddw147 what is the difference from LIMIT ? Sorry Im noob :(

Comment: @Andrew everybody is noob first time , check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp you will get some basics of mysql and for pagination check out this http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/view?login=Eweaver&preview=no&slideid=1&title=efficient-pagination-using-mysql

Comment: this is getting to broad.. but you can use `$_GET` variables like `yourphpfile.php?page=1` then use it, initialize: if not isset default to 1, else use the page number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the idea is:

- If the current page is the first page `(page 1)`, hide the `<`
- If the current page is the last page, hide the `>`

You can use `$_GET['page']` and use it as your marker for your current page:

```
http://youdomain.php?page=300
```

So first, you can initialize it:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Then determine the last page: `ceil(total number of rows / how many rows per page)`

Example: `PDO`

```
$check = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM TABLE_NAME'); // get total rows
$total_items = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['total']; // 5.4 above (dereference)
$total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit); // calculate how many pages
// of course this is the last page
```

So now, just use it on both conditions:

```
<div class="paging">
    <!-- previous -->
    <?php if($page != 1): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $page-1; ?>" title="Previous Page">&laquo;</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <span><?php echo $page; ?></span> <!-- current page -->

    <!-- next -->
    <?php if($page != $total_pages): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $page+1; ?>" title="Next Page">&raquo;</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Sample Logic:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME;charset=utf8', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// paginate using url get `?page=x` where x is a number
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$limit = 10; // default entries

$check = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM TABLE_NAME'); // get total rows
$total_items = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['total']; // 5.4 above
$total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit); // calculate how many pages
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit; // offset

// using limit offset
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT $offset, $limit");
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- just add other info -->
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<div class="paging">
    <?php if($page != 1): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $page-1; ?>" title="Previous Page">&laquo;</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span><?php echo $page; ?></span>
    <?php if($page != $total_pages): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $page+1; ?>" title="Next Page">&raquo;</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT offset, count
```